# Is there any reason why DeployBot isn't updating it's 'current' symlink folder?

Tags: web-deployment

I have setup an 'atomic sftp' server environment on DeployBot. When I deploy a new commit everything goes smoothly - no errors in the log - and the new release appears in the 'releases' folder on my server.

But the 'current' symlink which is supposed to point to the new release is not updating - instead it remains on an old release.

I have checked permissions for the folder, which is set to 0777. I can't think what else I need to do, as there don't seem to be any settings that refer to the symlink. Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

i ended up fixing this by deleting the 'current' symlink and re'deploying. i haven't had a problem since.